# How to change cron log level?

Tags: cron, upstart, services, systemd, log

I replaced `exec cron` with `exec cron -L 15` the run `sudo service cron reload`, `sudo service cron restart` but nothing changed. Cron doesn't log the end of jobs and doesn't log failed jobs. I hade no problem in Ubuntu 14.04, but now I have this problem in Ubuntu 16.04. What do I do wrong?

Step by Step:
First I changed /etc/init/cron.conf:

`sudo sed -i 's|exec cron$|exec cron -L15|' /etc/init/cron.conf && sudo restart cron && cat /etc/init/cron.conf`

So now it is

```
$ cat /etc/init/cron.conf
# cron - regular background program processing daemon
#
# cron is a standard UNIX program that runs user-specified programs at
# periodic scheduled times

description "regular background program processing daemon"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

expect fork
respawn

exec cron -L 15
```

I made the same config in my Ubuntu 16.04 as well as on Ubuntu 14.04 on the another PC.

The Cron log in Ubuntu 14.04 is the following:

```
$  grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Aug 26 16:05:01 y1404 CRON[6825]: (y) CMD (foo # JOB_ID_1)
Aug 26 16:05:01 y1404 CRON[6824]: (CRON) error (grandchild #6825 failed with exit status 127)
```

So you can see the second line with error notification about nonexistent command `foo`. But in Ubuntu 16.04 there is no error notification in the log:

```
Aug 26 16:25:01 my CRON[7259]: (y) CMD (foo # JOB_ID_129)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Ubuntu 15.04 on, **upstart** using `/etc/init/*.conf` is replaced by **systemd** using configuration files in `/lib/systemd/system/` and `/etc/systemd/system/`. Although a file `/etc/init/cron.conf` is still existent in Ubuntu 16.04, the script normally in use to start `cron` now is **`/lib/systemd/system/cron.service`**. If you want to add extra options, edit this file with

```
sudo systemctl edit --full cron
```

and replace the line

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS
```

by e. g.

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -L 15 -f $EXTRA_OPTS
```

To reload the configuration, run `sudo systemctl restart cron` or just reboot. You can test what exact command a service was started with using `systemctl status`, e. g. for `cron` (see last line):

```
> systemctl status cron
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since So 2017-08-27 09:56:18 CEST; 1h 15min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 26021 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─26021 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```